# How to get IPTC value above 65 characters limit?

Tags: php, limit, iptc

I want to retrieve more than 65 characters of the IPTC 2#005 value of a JPG image.

But when I use the classic :

```
$size = getimagesize($photo, $info);
if(isset($info['APP13']))
{
    $iptc = iptcparse($info['APP13']);
    return $iptc;
}
```

The phrase is truncated :

```
["2#005"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(64) "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, howev"
  }
```

But Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Bridge, Windows 10 Explorer, can display the whole string (above the 65 limit) in the photo metadatas ("When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?")

Do you know how to retrieve the whole string with PHP ? plz

Many thanks

Comment: I googled around a bit but  it seems like there is nothing to this topic …